# NativeScript/Angular - How to style checked state on a switch when using ngModel/FormBuilder?

Tags: css, angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular

Consider this switch:

```
<Switch class="switch" formControlName="answer"></Switch>
```

If I do this it only works when you haven't activated the switch yet, after that the background-color will always be the same even when the switch is not active:

```
.switch[checked=true] {
  background-color: #FE4A49;
  color: #FE4A49;
}
```

And if I do this:

```
.switch {
  background-color: #FE4A49;
  color: #FE4A49;
}
```

Then the background will always be the same regardless of the state.

What's the correct way of styling a switch when using it with angular's model bindings?

Answer (score 8):

i'm styling an App and this is i'd do.

CSS:

```
Switch#userStatus[checked=true]{
  color:#ff0048 ;
  background-color: white;
  transform: scale(1.25, 1.25); // This is for change the size when checked
  transform: translate(-5,0); // This is for stay the position after scale it
}

Switch#userStatus[checked=false]{
  color: gray;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

And this is my XML:

```
`<Switch id="userStatus" checked="false" />`
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue with switch

> background-color

and it was not working as expected. Changing the **background-color** was changing the whole switch (the gray part). So I had to change only the **color** property:

```
Switch[checked=true] {
    color: #f68533;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.switch-notchecked {
    background-color: #FE4A49;
    color: yellow;
}

.switch-checked {
    background-color: blue;
    color: green;
}
```

In your template

```
<Switch #sw checked="false" (checkedChange)="switchChanged(sw.checked)" [class]="isChecked?'switch-checked':'switch-notchecked'"></Switch>
```

In your component

```
isChecked:boolean;

 switchChanged(checked) {
        this.isChecked = checked;
    }
```

Comment: This isn't gonna work when using FormBuilder especially. Too much extra logic. I think the best way for now is to use ngClass along with a condition which checks the form control value directly.

Comment: It might work but you're not using any angular specific bindings, which isn't good cuz of validation.